# Polynomially Reduce Box-Depth to Max-Clique

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

Box-Depth Problem:

> Given $n$ rectangles, such that their sides are parralel to the
>   coordinate axes ($x$ and $y$), Find a subset with maximum size such
>   that the intersection of its members are not empty.

Max-Clique Problem:

> A simple graph $G$ is given. What is the size of the biggest complete subgraph (clique) of $G$?

---

**Question:**

Polynomially Reduce Box-Depth Problem to Max-Clique Problem.  (Provide a translation function)

---

Note: I was thinking of seeing a rectangle as a clique with $4$ nodes... But, This doesn't work out... Because this way, All of the cliques are of size $4$, and the answer to the problem would be always $4$... which is incorrect.

Comment: Hint : See a rectangle as a one vertex and edge means two rectangles are overlapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

You want to build a graph whose nodes are the rectangles. Two nodes are connected by an edge when the rectangles intersect.

How can you tell if a pair of rectangles intersect? Can you decide that for all pairs of rectangles in polynomial time?

**Edit:** My second thoughts led me to doubt this solution.
A clique in the graph is set of rectangles each pair of which intersect, but the question calls for a set with an empty intersection.

My third thoughts are that this is not a problem. For arbitrary rectangles, three can intersect in pairs without having a common point. But I am pretty sure you can prove that for any finite set of rectangles with axes parallel to the coordinate axes, pairwise intersection implies intersection.
I'll leave it up as a cautionary tale.

Comment: Excuse me... I don't get the idea... I'm lost somehow... Would you please explain more?

Comment: I can tell if just $2$ rectangles are given... By the coordinates, it can be done easily... But, all pairs means $n$ choose $2$, which is exponential.  Am i right?

Comment: $n$ choose $2$ is quadratic in $n$. There's an easy formula for it.

Comment: Yes you're right... My mistake... :)